# Black screen API level 11 Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I want to test my app on platform Android 3.0.x (API level 11). But I'm getting an black screen on my emulator below you can see a screenshot of it:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L35s7.png

I think I need `x86` as my `CPU/ABI`, because my other virtual devices use `x86` as you can see in the screenshot below:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdTMm.png

I have already installed everything I need for API level 11 as you can see in the screenshot below:

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzQ00.png

And here is a screenshot of Android SDK Manager to show you that I already have installed what I need link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmQDg.png

In the screenshot below you can see my settings of my virtual device:
link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIlgo.png

Here below you can see the details of my virtual device:

```
Name: Nexus_5_API_11

CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi)

Path: C:\Users\yomac_000\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_11.avd

Target: Google APIs (API level 11)

Skin: nexus_5

SD Card: C:\Users\yomac_000\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_11.avd\sdcard.img

Snapshot: no

hw.lcd.density: 480

hw.dPad: no

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.camera.back: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 200M

hw.gpu.enabled: no

runtime.network.latency: none

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.keyboard: yes

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.device.hash2: MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88

hw.ramSize: 1536

tag.id: default

tag.display: Default

hw.sdCard: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.device.name: Nexus 5

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.battery: yes

AvdId: Nexus_5_API_11

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

hw.camera.front: none

hw.gps: yes

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5 API 11

snapshot.present: no

vm.heapSize: 64

runtime.scalefactor: auto
```

Comment: what do u see on real device?

Comment: Why don't you try geny motion or online emulators

Comment: You try to use genymotion or cloud devices

Comment: you may be using a component or method that is not valid with API 11. Depending on the issue, you may not get a crash but something like this. Do you have a log file of what happens when it loads? Any debug info on where in your code it stops executing?

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade and ashutiwari4 I had tried Genymotion but API 11 wasn't available there.

Comment: @Jim before I had run my emulator I had cleared my logs. So when I was running the emulator I'm not seeing any logs. Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/QTvh138.png

Comment: Hi, go to `Help -> Check for updates` click on blue link updates, change both to Canary Channel. You would get a new Android Studio with fixed logcat bug (yes, empty log is well-known problem) and NEW BRAND EMULATOR. Maybe this would help

Comment: Yes, Genymotion doesn't support API 11, but is it a problem to afford a phone with this API?

Comment: @superkytoz - your screenshot shows ADM with a device status of "disconnected" - so there won't be logs...

Comment: @Jim My bad I had sent you the wrong screenshot. Here is the right screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/WbYoZaw.png

As you can see it gives no logs. Also I didn't clear the logs. Here is a another screenshot of the run tab: http://i.imgur.com/GBaBb3r.png

Comment: @superkytoz - you probably have a filter on that prevents anything from displaying. In the screenshot your emulator is covering the area where it displays "filters" - turn everything off until you see logs. Logcat has frequent output from the system, if nothing else, so you should see *something*

Comment: @Jim You were right. I have made 2 screenshots of the errors. Here are the screenshots if you want to see them: link 1: http://i.imgur.com/rKpaAFC.png  and link 2: http://i.imgur.com/JAx9LSK.png  Also I would like to mention that the emulator was printing the logs non-stop.

Comment: @superkytoz - those are a lot of garbage collection calls. Now when you load your app, pay attention to what is happening before all of that. Looks like a memory leak or it simply got stuck. Also check the View Hierarchy to see what is actually attached to the window.